# what causes the error in vobjtovarid?

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to read some variables from the necdf file but I am getting an error:

```
 f=open.ncdf("mrgHYDRO_Az_arfswp_Stom_PRUNI_20000101_20001231_1M_sechiba_history.nc")
 A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="Evaporation",verbose=TRUE)
 Error in vobjtovarid(nc, varid, verbose = verbose) : Variable not found
```

Any help please,Best Regards

```
  "file has 9 dimensions:"
        [1] "lon   Size: 34"
         [1] "lat   Size: 30"
        [1] "veget   Size: 13"

  "file  has 113 variables:"
   [1] "double time_counter_bnds[tbnds,time_counter]  Longname:time_counter_bnds Missval:1e+30"
    [1] "float evap[lon,lat,time_counter]  Longname:Evaporation Missval:1e+30"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct name to refer to in the call to `get.var.ncdf` is `evap` not `Evaporation`. The longname is just a more descriptive name, the real name is `evap`.

```
A = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="evap",verbose=TRUE)
```